Cartoon with dinosaur named Scott
There was a cartoon (probably around 1990) with a dinosaur named "Scott" (or something like this). He had his purpose to reach the green valley. Although he didn't manage too, he was happy because he had his friends with his all this time.
Could you please identify this TV-cartoon-series?

It might be Dink, the Little Dinosaur, which have character name Scat (A Compsognathus).

The series originally aired on the CBS Kids block on CBS from 1989 to 1991.
There is also a cartoon film from 1988 The Land Before Time, which shows the dinosaurs search for the Great Valley (Without any scott named dinosaurs ) but it also made in a TV-series and few sequel films.

perfect. could you tell me who is dink and who is scat? (colors)?

@ThanosDarkadakis the smaller one is scat and taller green is Dink.
